# Main CSS override properties

Tags: css, websitebaker

I am using the CMS called WebsiteBaker, now I wrote a module for it, a droplet, that uses it's own CSS.
It seems to be that the CSS of the droplet cannot be overriden by the main CSS.

I assume that's because the droplet (and along with it, the css) is loaded after everything else.
And I cannot just modify the CMS files as workaround, as it's a module.

Any ideas for a workaround or something similar?

--

Main CSS (override attempt, included in the header)

```
#programma_tab {
    width: 300px;
}
```

Droplet CSS Example (included in the body, there is no other way)

```
#programma_tab {
    padding: 5px;
    font-size: 12px;
    margin-top: -15px;
    width: 200px;
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I have a couple of ideas.

1 - Try making the selectors more specific. Something like `body` should override the original

```
body #programma_tab {
    padding: 5px;
    font-size: 12px;
    margin-top: -15px;
    width: 200px;
}
```

2 - try adding `!important` after any CSS property.

```
#programma_tab {
    padding: 5px !important;
    font-size: 12px !important;
    margin-top: -15px !important;
    width: 200px !important;
}
```

Comment: +1 for the more specific. If you can make the selectors more specific, it will override the defaults. That way is definitely better than `!important`

Comment: Why would adding body infront of the selector override it though?

Comment: Because it's more specific. `#programma_tab` would ask for the element with ID `programma_tab`. However `body #programma_tab` would ask for the element with the id of `programma_tab` that is a child of `body`.

Answer (score 1):

If you are using the [DropletsExtension for WebsiteBaker](https://blog.phpmanufaktur.de/de/article/dropletsextension-der-nachbrenner.php) the CSS for your Droplet can be automatically loaded in the head section of the template and you don't need to put your CSS hardcoded into the body.

Comment: Upvote, because hardcoding in body is "evil". Yet, why would css be put into droplet code in the first place? Any reason not to put it into template css file? -> all in one place, clean, no override issues etc.

Comment: Droplets are no regular addons, just small chunks of code which will be executed within any WYSIWYG page, therefore they are not recognized by the CMS and they can not tell the system to load a CSS file. This is what the DropletsExtension enable for the Droplets through a backdoor.

Answer (score 0):

Just add a `!important` statement to the CSS commands like:

```
#programma_tab {
    padding: 5px !important;
    font-size: 12px !important;
    margin-top: -15px !important;
    width: 200px !important;
}
```

I know its certainly not the most elegant way, but it works.

Comment: This should be seen as a temporary fix though. It could end up overriding things you don't want to be overridden and it looks awful.

Comment: Was the downvote really neccessary? It's not as if his answer isn't working.

Comment: @NullBy7e There's a difference between not working and not recommended. I would strongly recommend going with the more specific selector option.